# How to customize "required" error messages using a dictionary on VeeValidate (Vue.Js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I would like to change the error message when an input with "cpf" rule isn't filled (in other words, when an input with "cpf"rule didn't satisfy the "required" rule).

I think that the "dictionary method" with custom messages should do the work, but I couldn't make it work.

With the code below, the error message displayed is just the ***default pt_br*** message for "required" fields. I would like to display the message in the dictionary **dict** below ("**Favor preencher o cpf**")

In my **main.js**, I have the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import './core/extensions';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

And on **extensions.js**:

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import VeeValidate, { Validator } from 'vee-validate';
 import ptBR from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/pt_BR';

 const dict = {
     messages: ptBR.messages,
     pt_BR: {
      custom: {
         cpf: {
           required: 'Favor preencher o cpf',
         },
       }
     },
   };

Vue.use(VeeValidate);

Validator.localize({ pt_BR: dict })

Validator.extend('cpf', (val) => {
     return false //just to test
});
```

**App.vue** (simple example):

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" v-validate="required|cpf">      
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm using `vee-validate 2.1.5` and `vue 2.5.17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the validator is using `cpf` as a field name rather than a validation rule in this case.

I'm not clear on why the `cpf` rule should trigger the `required` rule, but if you give the input a `name` or `data-vv-name` attribute like:

```
<input type="text" data-vv-name="cpf" v-validate="required">
```

and pass the following arguments to `localize`:

```
Validator.localize('pt_BR', {
  custom: {
    cpf: {
      required: 'Favor preencher o cpf'
    }
  }
})
```

That will display your localized message when the field is empty.

Here's an example of a field specific error message (replace 'en' with 'pt_BR' as needed)

```js
VeeValidate.Validator.localize('en', {
  custom: {
    cpf: {
      required: 'Favor preencher o cpf'
    }
  }
})

Vue.use(VeeValidate)

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
p {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@latest"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" data-vv-name="cpf" v-validate="'required'">
  <p>{{ errors.first('cpf') }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using the ValidationProvider? I named it using data-vv-name="cpf" and used rules="required", but the error message displayed was "O campo {field} é obrigatório". Using name="cpf" the error displayed was  "O campo cpf é obrigatório". I think the dictionary isn't been considered for some reason

Comment: The validation provider and observer components are excellent additions to VeeValidate. They've resolved a number of validation challenges that required overly complex, hack solutions, namely related to injection and scoping. Since their release they have been all I've used.

Comment: Nice to hear that the Provider is a good option! But, I have no idea why the dictionary isn’t working

Answer (score 0):

I felt custom error message is not working with ValidateProvider component.

Answer (score 0):

I got the easy way of vee-validate to customize error messages:
1- first install package vee-validate using following command

```
npm install vee-validate --save
```

2- import and register the following in main.js

```
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm';
import { ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate';
Vue.component('ValidationProvider',ValidationProvider);
Vue.component('ValidationObserver',ValidationObserver);
```

3- Now move to your component and make an input field:

```
 <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
                            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(additem)">
                                <ValidationProvider name="Item" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label>Item</label>
                                        <textarea rows="5" id="item" data-vv-as="item1"  class="form-control" v-model="item"></textarea>
                                        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </ValidationProvider>

                                <div class="row mt-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" >Save Item</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </ValidationObserver>
```

4- Now import localize where from you are importing ValidationProvider as following
in your vue component in script tag.

```
import {localize} from "vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm";
localize({

    en: {
        fields: {
            Item: {
                required: "Please enter some title",
                // alpha: "please enter alphabets only"
            }
        }
    }
});
    localize("en");
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [Field-specific Custom Messages](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/messages.html#field-specific-custom-messages) in the official documentation.

You basically have to provide a custom dict for each language you want to override.

Comment: This link does not exists.